# Regular Expressions with Python fix to exclude final digits after space

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression and is actually including the # 4 at the end (that there is after space). How should I adjust the expression to avoid include the #4 after space?

```
((U|u)((S|s)|\$)((D|d)|(S|s)))+((.|,)\d+)*
```

Strings:

```
USD1.221 4
USD 1,221 4
```

Comment: can you tell more about the regular expression, what it's intended for and some example would be nice.

Comment: Rather than (.|,) = any character, code [.,].
+ is not appropriate as quantifier for the currency, it is better to code in the form (USD|\$). 
The form of the value  (1.221) should be made more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[Uu][Ss][$Dd]\s?\d[\d.,]*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/5Sg5Ip/1). The expression matches `US$` or `USD`, followed with an optional whitespace and then a digit and zero or more digits, periods or commas.